# file_exists & is_file not working

Tags: php, sqlite

I am using this code:

```
$DataSourceName = "..\Log4OM\Log4OM-Active.SQLite";
if(!file_exists($DataSourceName))
{
    $Msg = sprintf("%s does not exist", $DataSourceName);
    die($Msg);
}
```

The file really does exist, and this path has been working until this morning.  Now the test fails and the application dies.  "is_file" fairs no better.

I also use this code:

```
$connection = new PDO("sqlite:".$DataSourceName);
    // Set errormode to exceptions
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

This actually does open the file and the application runs normally. I know this because I defeated the first test to try it.  Unfortunately the first test must pass before I get to the "$connection =" line.

I also tried fopen, which fails to open the file.  The file name is actually a hard link to the real file, but substituting the real file name has the same problem.  File permissions look to be correct and the same as several days ago.

Comment: Are you sure that `$DataSourceName` is a correct path?

Comment: Yes I am.  $DataSourceName is also used in the "new PDO" statement and works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't rely on directory "walking". Always specify the root from where you are starting with (for example) `__DIR__`

```
$DataSourceName = __DIR__ . "\..\Log4OM\Log4OM-Active.SQLite";
if(!file_exists($DataSourceName))
{
    $Msg = sprintf("%s does not exist", $DataSourceName);
    die($Msg);
}
```

Comment: I find it's easier to specify something a bit more static, such as `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, so you don't have to recalculate the path for every single directory.

Comment: Sure. It's an example. You may have a defined constant somewhere with document_root, you may do dirname(\_\_FILE__) there are many options. The bottom line is DO NOT TRUST _default_ file location.

Comment: The document_root is one of the [$_SERVER superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). It almost always exists when accessing the script via browser, but not usually when using it on the command line. Just stating it as an easy global way to specify a file path -- easier to copy/paste across the project.

Comment: SOLVED - aynber & Unamata, That did it.  I ended up using the $_SERVER version.  Odd that the script had worked since this past January on a daily basis, and just now failed.